# how to use a variable to $lookup a mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have 3 collections: users, wallets and currencies.

I need to make a query that gets every user that has a wallet of a given currency.

Users dont share properties with currencies, but wallets share properties with both.

Users have and _id and wallets have a corresponding _userId. And wallets have a currency property that is a string and corresponds to the name property currencies have.

Is it possible to use a previously defined currencyName variable to check for equality and get every wallet from a user that has this currency?

Right now im using an aggregation with a match, and i would like to add this on top.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {some matches}
  },
  { 
    $lookup: //I assume I need to use a $lookup but i cant figure out if its possible to use a         variable here.
  },
  {
    $project
  }, etc
]);
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide some of your json documents and the expected output

Comment: Is the `currencies` collection necessary for the `"$lookup"` if the `wallets` collection has a string property that uniquely identifies the currency?

Comment: Hey guys i solved it doing it the other way around. Instead of taking the matches made on the user collection i aggregated on the Wallet collection, $match on the currency, then $lookup on users collection.